# What is wrong with this Fargesia?

Tags: pest-control, plant-health, bamboo

Looks like some kind of leaf miner, but I've never seen it before. What is it, and is there an "organic" way to treat it?

[image: Fargesia]
[image: Fargesia 2]
[image: Fargesia 3]

Comment: looks more like a virus/fungus/bacteria.  Is there anyone living on the underside of the leaf?

Comment: The underside is shown in the middle photo. The only thing i noticed were tje small black spots near the edge. I didnt have my hand loupe so couldnt see any better.

Comment: Could be thrips which are common in some areas of the US. They leave black frass on the leaves  and the adults are the size of exclamation marks.  They will move when jostled.  Can you check if anything moves on the leaf?

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is 23F in this picture. No buggies moving.

Comment: Do the black spots come off?

Comment: @kevinsky The black spots on the bottom were superficial and could be brushed off. I'm not sure if the spots visible from the top of the leaf are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking around unsuccessfully for references to thrips on bamboo, I came across what appears to be a likely suspect - [bamboo mites](http://seattlebamboo.com/mite.html). The mottling on the leaves is consistent with what is pictured, as are the small black spots on the underside of the leaves. The final tell are the small, low profile, tents as shown in the photo below.

[image: Bamboo mite tents]

Oregon State University has a good guide for [controlling bamboo mites](http://oregonstate.edu/dept/nurspest/Bamboo/references.htm). Additionally, [this source](http://www.bamboobotanicals.ca/html/bamboo-care/bamboo-mites/Bamboo-Mites-WSU.pdf) covers potential biological controls.

Answer (score 2):

Without a close-up photo my guess is Thrips.  Easy to manage, sucking insects.  Here is a good article on control.  Get a hand lens to make absolutely sure this is your target insect before applying any pesticide.  I'd thin out some of the foliage before treating.

[Thrip control](http://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/houseplant-pests/thrips-control/)